# grep line containing a pattern to line containing other pattern

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk, grep

Say the input is:

```
">"1aaa         
 2           
 3    
 4   
">"5bbb   
 6    
 7   
">"8ccc   
 9  
">"10ddd   
 11   
 12
```

I want this output (per example for the matching pattern "bbb"):

```
">"5bbb   
 6  
 7
```

I had tried with grep:

```
grep -A 2 -B 0 "bbb" file.txt > results.txt
```

This works. However, the number of lines between `">"5bbb` and `">"8ccc` are variable. Does anyone knows how to achieve that using Unix command line tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk` you could simply using a flag like so:

```
$ awk '/^">"/{f=0}/bbb/{f=1}f' file
">"5bbb
 6
 7
```

You could also parametrize the pattern like so:

```
$ awk '/^">"/{f=0}$0~pat{f=1}f' pat='aaa' file
">"1aaa
 2
 3
 4
```

**Explanation**:

```
/^">"/   # Regular expression that matches lines starting ">"
{f=0}    # If the regex matched unset the print flag
/bbb/    # Regular expression to match the pattern bbb
{f=1}    # If the regex matched set the print flag
f        # If the print flag is set then print the line
```

Comment: @janos
In some files, I have multiple lines containing the pattern bbb. The awk command line outputs all lines containing the pattern bbb. However, the matching pattern should be found only in lines containg also >. I don't understand the second part of the command with {f=0} and {f=1} and really I don't know how to modify the command line...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
sed -ne '/bbb/,/^"/ { /bbb/p; /^[^"]/p; }' file.txt
```

That is:

- for the range of lines between matching `/bbb/` and `/^"/`
- if the line matches `/bbb/` print it
- if the line doesn't start with `"` print it
- otherwise nothing else is printed

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^"/h;G;/\n.*bbb/P;d' file
```